# What exercise to perform at the gym to be able to perform muscle ups?

Tags: exercise, muscle-ups

Just wondering what set of exercises do you recommend to be able to perform muscle ups ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ring dips and ring pull ups (with false grip) in ordinary gym rings.

If one or both of these exercises are too hard then replace ring pull ups with pull ups (strict or with kipping) in the bar or lower the rings until your feets touches the floor during the exercise. Replace ring dibs for instance with dips between two boxes.

You can also apply a rubberband between the rings and let your knees rest on the band for dips and sit on the band for pull ups.

When you are in the rings: Remember to do simple exercises pressing your shoulders in the opposite direction of gravity to avoid injuries.

"Muscle ups" is an advanced exercise. You must have been doing core exercises and common functional exercises for your upper body for a while to stabilize your body and to avoid injuries.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to be able to do pull ups and chest dips.

To train for muscle ups you will need to do lots of both of those two exercises.

Pull ups and chest dips account for most of the muscle up move however the most difficult part of a muscle up is the transition. False grip training is highly recommended to improve the transition part of a muscle up. So incorporate false grip hangs and false grip pull ups.

Aside from that, all you can do is the full muscle up move but with assistance, the same as when you probably first started doing pull ups; rest your legs on a stool or something to take some of the weight. Do the move quickly with a bit of a jump at the start. Go to the top of the move and then slowly go down to a hang.